# Loop over XML and store attributes in a struct

Tags: xml, go, struct

I query a device and it returns an XML output with the number of alerts.
I want to store each alert as a struct and store all the alerts in a slice.

I have looked through a number of answers for a similar problem but I am having a hard time finding how to parse the attributes of each msg tag and put the attributes into the struct.

Example Code: https://play.golang.org/p/XZMONjRc5q1

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.* (Not at an external link.)

Answer (score 1):

I have made corrections to your example code [on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UmzRjGP2my5).

- Your XML example was not well-formed; the first `<msg>` element was missing a closing tag, so there would've been parse errors.
- Your outer element is not named `"xml version"`. Your outer element is the `<alarmlist>`, which contains zero or more elements named `<msg>`.
- Values contained by `<msg>` are not elements. They are *attributes* and must be tagged appropriately.

I imagine this is not the only XML document your code will need to handle in the long run, so I recommend you read [the godoc](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal) *very* carefully to understand the tag syntax. Look for [introductions to XML](https://www.sitepoint.com/really-good-introduction-xml/) on the nets if you're having trouble with some of the terminology.

Comment: My opinion, which is not part of the answer, is that [XML kind of sucks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Criticism) and is an interchange format of last resort. Virtually all data structures in Go can be logically tagged with _both_ `xml:""` _and_ `json:""` tags, which to me pretty straightforwardly implies that JSON, which uses fewer characters, needs fewer rules, and can still be easily pretty-printed and parsed, is the superior format in nearly all cases....

Answer (score -1):

I had to add the attr to the vbcAlert struct.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your answer would be improved by explaining how it addresses the question. See stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer